# Asp.net mvc Html.ActionLink not working in Bootstrap Select

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a dropdown list for my localization choice of my page. But if I tried to do this with `<ul>` tags Html.ActionLink helper creates true link with language code like below

```
 @{
    var routeValues = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values;
    var controller = routeValues["controller"] as string;
    var action = routeValues["action"] as string;
  }

 <ul>
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("TR", @action, @controller, new { culture = "tr" }, new { rel = "alternate", hreflang = "tr" })
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("EN", @action, @controller, new { culture = "en" }, new { rel = "alternate", hreflang = "en" })
    </li>
</ul>
```

But if I want to do that in Bootstrap select control it only displays text in and not goes to my url.

```
<select class="bs-select form-control" data-width="auto" id="js-data-example-ajax" name="js-data-example-ajax">
    <option>@Html.ActionLink("TR", @action, @controller, new {culture = "tr"}, new {rel = "alternate", hreflang = "tr"})</option>
    <option>@Html.ActionLink("EN", @action, @controller, new { culture = "en" }, new { rel = "alternate", hreflang = "en" })</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have other option like this

```
<option data-url="@Url.Action(@action, @controller)">
 TR
</option>
```

your dropdown change event in jquery look like

```
$('#js-data-example-ajax').on('change', function() {
        var yourUrl = $('#js-data-example-ajax').find(":selected").data('url');
        document.location = yourUrl ;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in my project the same thing please refer below code :

I have done this using JavaScript.

**My .cshtml code :**

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "url",
    new SelectList(new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "About", Value = Url.Action("About", "Home") },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "MyPage", Value = Url.Action("Index", "Home") },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "APage", Value = Url.Action("AnyPage", "Home") },
    }, "Value", "Text"),
    "-- Pick an URL ---",
    new { id = "urlddl" }
)
```

**My JQuery Code :**

```
$(function() {
    $('#urlddl').change(function() {
        var url = $(this).val();
        if (url != null && url != '') {
            window.location.href = url;
        }
    });
});
```

using jQuery you could subscribe for the change event of this dropdownlist and navigate to the corresponding URL.

Hope it will solve your problem.

Thanks